# How it is possible to show a alert for thank you if user allow push notification in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

the problem is that the alert for allow or not allow for push notification  comes from server then how can I recognise the buttonAtIndex delegate method of alertview. what is the best solution for this.. and the another issue is how it is possible to show the alertview of push notification in every 5 min if the user not allow for the push notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question-1**

Ans : if user press the `Allow` , the following delegate method is call.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken{

NSLog(@"device token is: %@",deviceToken);
// In here add your Alertview for Thank you

}
```

if user press `Not Allow` the following delegate method is called

```
   -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
    {
     // in here add your 5 minutes method call
    }
```

**Question-2**

payload receving method is

```
   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
                                                    fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)   (UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

    NSLog(@"Notification received: %@", userInfo);
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

**call method in 5 minutes**

```
   -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
    {
     // in here add your 5 minutes method call
       [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5*60 target:self selector:@selector(showAlertforenableAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }


- (void) showAlert:(NSTimer *) timer {
UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"yourtitle!" 
                                                 message:@"yourmessage!" 
                                                delegate:self               
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];

}
```

Comment: would u need any support for this

Comment: Sir I have done as you says. but i find that didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method calls every time when i launched my app. and didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError will not not called when i clicked on not allow button in real device.

Comment: once if you allowed it caled only didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method, need to clear or try in another system

Comment: Yes Sir I have Done.

Answer (score 0):

i am not clear about ur first issue. but In second case, you can add local notification for alert view when user not allowing push notification. that will get called after specific time as you will mention.

Comment: Sir the alertview for asking do you want to allow push notification or not, is coming from server then i want that if the user allow for push notification then I want show popup for thank you.

Comment: its mean how can I know user allow for push notification in my app?

Comment: What do you mean by the alert which comes from the server?